# gazebo9 no longer opens up

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

After building a ROS package which requires gazebo9 dependency, my gazebo stoped working. I already had gazebo9 working in my system prior to this.

In my terminal I use the 'gazebo --verbose` command line:

```
gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgazebo_common.so.9: undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition10fuel_tools12ClientConfig12SetUserAgentERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I don't want to have to reinstall gazebo9 if I don't have to. Is there a way to fix this problem without doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to other [forum](https://answers.ros.org/question/327766/i-installed-ros-melodic-for-my-1804-unbuntu-but-i-couldnt-launch-gazebo-with-the-gazebo-command/) you should upgrade one library via

```
$ sudo apt upgrade libignition-math2
```

or some other [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gazebo/+bug/1824094) by running the `gazebo` command as

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-fuel_tools2.so.2 gazebo
```